# how do I mount a SharePoint site faster via intune?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, intune

I have an Intune policy which should automatically include a SharePoint website (document library).
Using the policy "Configure team website libraries for automatic synchronization" this works more or less but only after some time. If I e.g. integrate a new device and pull the apps and policies everything is available after a few seconds/minutes on the device except this one policy several reboots do not help only after several hours the SharePoint page is integrated into the explorer...

How can I speed up the whole thing now?

Best regards

Comment: A way to speed up the sync process is to use the SharePoint On Demand feature. This allows you to only download the files when they are needed, rather than syncing the entire library to the device. Here is a link to the Microsoft documentation on how to configure this feature:

Configure on-demand synchronization for SharePoint libraries in Microsoft Intune
Additionally, you can try using PowerShell scripts to automate the process of mounting SharePoint sites. Here is a link to an example PowerShell script that may be useful:

Intune PowerShell script to map SharePoint libraries